# How can I fix a pager limited to 2 pages?

Tags: 7, paging

The pager on the home page of my website is limited to 2 pages, ie the paging links are only for page 1 and 2 and both `next` and `last` point to page 2, but there are a lot more pages than that.

Is there some setting which controls this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set items per page for the Home page at `Configuration/System/Site information/FRONT PAGE` as shown in following image:

> [image]

And you can check also how many nodes you have promoted to the frontpage  at `Admin/Content`. So these two settings will allow you set all this. Hope this will work.

**Additional:**

If you want more settings for the FrontPage, you can go to `Admin/Structure/Views/` and you can see a view named `FrontPage`, that is by default disabled. But you can enable. And that view works as a FrontPage. So in views setting you can set as you want.

Comment: When I check the Front Page settings on my system the dropdown for selecting the number of posts goes to a maximum of 30, but although I have set it to 30 it still displays a maximum of 20

Comment: @vfclists I did check, ideally it should not show the different number of items than what it was set. I should not mention but please check the total number of nodes you have created and how much are set for `published to front-page`. and please also check whether you have enabled the views `FrontPage` and its pager.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for calculating how many nodes are set for `published to front-page`?

Comment: I do not have that. But you can just find whether there is 30 or more that 30 items which has the status of promoted to front-page or not. You can go to `Admin/Find content`, there under section of `Show only items where` filter it for `promoted` content. and then you can simply count whether  the filtered content is more that 30 or not. If more that 30, 30 items it should so on the front-page. So, this way you can check whether your site has at-least 30 promoted  node or not. If there is only 20, then whether if you set 25 or 30, it will show 20 only.

Comment: Using the frontpage view worked. For some reason the settings used on the Site Information page do not work properly